# Can't add background image into Jumbotron for Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a rails app built with devise and I can't seem to add a background image to my jumbotron on the home page.

The image file is app/assets/images/background.jpg.

Here is the html for the home page located in app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>redacted</h1>
    <p class="lead">redacted</p>
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="users/sign_up" role="button">Sign up today</a>      </p></div>
```

In app/assets/stylesheets/home.css I've added the following code:

```
 .jumbotron {
 background: url('../images/background.jpg');
 }
```

Any help as to why the background image won't render would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you apply your css code after Bootstrap style sheet.

app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css
app/assets/stylesheets/home.css

Look here [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/0zyLfdJCPk)

Comment: Thank's. I am not the question's owner, but your answer saved my day :)